# Compress Json Objects by Field JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8}]
```

is there a command in JQuery/JS or any other HTML compatible language that will allow me to convert the above JSON into the following:

```
[{"state":"MN","value":[10,10,10]},{"state":"NY","value":[8,8,8]}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Simply iterate the original object and create the desired output

Answer (score 3):

Below looping will give you the desired output,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gJp88/1/)

```
var data = [{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8}];

var tmp = {};
var t;
$.each (data, function (i, val) {
   if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(val.state)) {
      t = tmp[val.state];
      t.push(val.value);
   } else {
      tmp[val.state] = [val.value];
   }   
});

var output = [];
for (i in tmp) {
    output.push({'state': i, 'value': tmp[i]});   
}
```

**Proof:**

[image]

Comment: Dude, you're +1'ing non-jQuery answers are uses `$.each` in an answer that completely doesn't need it at all? Other than this, nice code :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
var input=[{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"MN","value":10},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8},{"state":"NY","value":8}]

var tmp={}, output=[];
while(o=input.pop()) (tmp[o.state] || (tmp[o.state]=[])).push(o.value); //you could even stop here if it is enough for you
for(k in tmp) output.push({state:k,value:tmp[k]});
```

Comment: I like simplifying and optimizing everything ^^

Comment: I wouldn't call optimized as you are calling array `.shift()` which is an overkill. Instead you can use `.pop` which doesn't shift the elements.. but again a for loop iterate is generally faster in this case as we gonna just read.

Comment: With V8, it shows better results with shift, http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-shift-on-a-array/ but it seems in not the case everywhere and pop seems to be faster. I change it to pop right now ;)